# Unique field in react-admin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I use `No` field as the order is very important for my list items. The problem is how I validate `No` values if it is a fresh value.

```
Previous list - [{No: 1, ...}, {No: 2, ...}] 
Create new item with No = 1 should be warned.
```

Please give me any ideas to solve this problem.

Comment: Hey, have you found a solution? I'm having the same problem.